# Droid Incredible not recognized by Eclipse after Gingerbread upgrade

Tags: android, eclipse

I had to wipe the device before the system upgrade from 2.2 would work. After the upgrade to 2.3.4 it no longer shows up in Eclipse's Devices tab. I've set the usual debugging options on the phone and updated the Android SDK Manager but no luck. I noticed that the SDK Manager has 2.3.1 and 2.3.3 options but nothing for 2.3.4 which I am now running. Do I need a new USB driver, and if so, from where? Maybe some other simple phone setting I've forgotten? Running Helios on Windows 7. All suggestions appreciated.

Comment: What does it do in Windows when connected? Do you get the USB messages in systray, Is it even recognised in windows as a removable disc??

Comment: Hey, that was the exact right question, apesa! Instead of the normal 2 drives it showed as an auto-run device. It didn't work because I had auto-run turned off on my PC. So I turned auto-run back on and reconnected the phone and eventually it looked normal in Windows. On restarting Eclipse the phone now shows up in the Devices view! Put your question in the form of an answer and I will accept it. Thanks for giving me the key, apesa.

Comment: Thanks and glad it helped, but I did not really have an answer, just a second pair of eyes so to speak.

Comment: I think this should be moved to android.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Turning off auto-play was the key. apesa asked exactly the right question which led me to discover the problem was that the USB drivers for the upgraded phone did not install due to the fact that I keep auto-play turned off on my PC. Allowing auto-play to do its magic solved my huge frustration. Note that this issue may apply to many more devices than just the Incredible.